# i3 windows manager conditional exec comand

Tags: desktop-environment, i3

Is there way to execute a command when a workspace is on?
I mean, if i go to a specific workspace (using $mod+5 workspace 5) a command is run (but only once). In summary, execute something like this.

```
if workspace5_on=true
  exec firefox
if firefox_is_on_workspace5=true
  do nothing
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are looking for a hook for when you switch workspaces?

Comment: mm i don't know. What is a hook? I am looking for to start once a command when i switch workspace. For example, when a switch to work space 3, firefox start, buy only once.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking

Comment: Probably, but I don't run i3 and cannot test. Could you install `wmctrl` and post the output of `wmctrl -d`, when you are *not* on workspace 1? What is your distro?

Comment: I'm not sure if this can be done in the i3 config file directly, but you can always write a script that does the workspace switching and process starting and execute that instead of the `workspace` command on `$mod+5`. Unfortunately I don't have a machine with i3 near me at the moment to write that script and test it.

Comment: I use linux mint    wmctrl -d
    0  - DG: N/A  VP: 0,0  WA: N/A  1 Main
    1  * DG: N/A  VP: 0,0  WA: N/A  2 Code